# Make htaccess put all directories into a single get variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am working with a CMS that needs pretty urls.
I found this snippet of htaccess code that I thought would solve all my problems:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?route=$1
```

Then on index.php I put this:

```
echo $_GET['route'];
```

If I go to mywebsite.com/cars, I can see "cars". Perfect. But if I go to mywebsite.com/cars/ford, I get a "page not found". What am I doing wrong? I want everything after the first "/" to be stuck into the route variable so I can explode it and make magic.

Comment: I've tried all the solutions provided and they work, but I'm having problems with the links in my pages. If I go to mysite.com/cars, it works. But once I add another directory, or even a trailing slash, the images, css, etc in my index.php try to load from that directory (mysite.com/cars/style.css).

Comment: Also, my links are relative... do they have to be absolute? I guess I'm thinking htaccess is a little more powerful than it actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work flawlessly:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

You don't have to pass the URL as a GET parameter to your script, because that would cause additional headaches about escaping special characters. You can easily access your URL via $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Comment: That works to capture everything... but I'm having problems with the links in my pages. If I go to http://mysite.com/cars, it works. But once I add another directory, or even a trailing slash, my images/css/etc in my index.php try to load from that directory (mysite.com/cars/style.css). I thought those rewrite conditions were supposed to take care of that?

Comment: That's a different problem. You need to reference your CSS/JS files with absolute path (leading /) in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks! I'm up and running now.

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in your .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php)(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

`\w` does not match slashes `/`. You need `.+` instead of `\w+`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ./index.php?route=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try this as .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

Get the query part (e.g. /a/b/c) like this:

```
$route = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

And explode it:

```
$arr = explode('/', $route)
```

The $arr[0] is the php script you want to run and $arr[1..n] is the query part.